# fetch each path from a network object in R

Tags: r, nodes, graph-theory

I have a binary adjacency matrix from which I have created a network:

```
net <- as.network(x = df3[1:300,1:300], # the network object
                  directed = TRUE, # specify whether the network is directed
                  loops = FALSE, # do we allow self ties (should not allow them)
                  matrix.type = "adjacency" # the type of input)
```

I can plot the network and it is some thing like that:

[image: plot of the network]

Now I want to fetch each path of a network separately as a list, but I am unable to find a way for that.